# Is ElGamal still unforgeable if the adversary knows r?

Tags: elgamal-signature, forgery

Is ElGamal still unforgeable if the adversary knows the value of $r$ that was calculated by $g^k$?

When we do sign the message $msg$, we calculate $r = g^k$.

As we know, the regular ElGamal is existentially forgeable:

- $e$ is picked randomly from $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$
- $r = g^e \cdot y$ mod $p$ and $s$ is $-r$ mod $p$
- When we check if it was forged we check for $y^r \cdot r^s = g^m$. Thus $g^{xr} \cdot (g^{e} y)^ {-r} = g^{-er} = g^{es} = g^m$. Where $m = H(msg)$.

if now $m = H(msg) + r$ (concatenate $r$ to $H(msg)$ is it now unforgable ?

Comment: $r$ is part of the signature. That value needs to be known, otherwise you cannot verify a signature. Do you mean $k$?

Comment: No i don't. In regular attack we say that g^xr (g^e y)^-r = g^-er = g^es = g^m. where m = h(M). if now m  is something like r + h(M) is it still unforgable

Comment: could you please edit this into the question and describe what your variables are.

Comment: yes i will do that

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you mix things up.

ElGamal signatures are existentially forgeable in various different ways if it's **not** using the hash-then-sign paradigm, i.e., you sign the message directly instead of signing the message $m=H(M)$ with $H$ being a secure cryptographic hash function.

Given the type of forgery in your question that works, you compute your $m$ as $m=es \bmod p-1$ and have no full control over the choice of $m$. Note that you would have to find $M$ such that $m=H(M)$ for your forgery to be valid, which means that you need a preimage $M$ of $m$ under $H$ which is not feasible if $H$ is secure. This is because the verification algorithm will get $M$ and signature $(r,s)$ and will check if $$y^r r^s\equiv g^{H(M)} \pmod p $$ holds.

You could modify the computation to $m=H(M)\|r$ and to adapt the verification algorithm to check if $y^r r^s\equiv g^{H(M)\|r} \pmod p $, but I do not see any immediate reason why you should do so. AFAIK hashing the message prevents any existential forgeries of ElGamal signatures as long as $H$ is secure.

Comment: I am not sure that concatenating r will not help you in some why. Such as eventually you will be able to forge every message.

Comment: @borgnimor ah ok, you proposed this as a countermeasure to existential forgeability? I didn't get this before. I do not really see problems with your approach but I do not see any point for doing so, if hashing is already sufficient.